# After Reset the Value of Textbox Tab is not working in React

Tags: reactjs

I have Developed one Simple form with two Textbox like

```
 <div className="form-group">
               <div className="col-md-6">
                 <input type="text" className="form-control input-lg" ref="firstname" required='required' />
               </div>
               <div className="col-md-6">
                 <input type="text" className="form-control input-lg" ref="lastname" required='required' />
               </div>
           </div>
```

on Submit Click I am trying to clear both the value using

```
   this.refs.firstname.value='';
   this.refs.lastname.value='';
```

this is working fine but once the fields clear Tab is not working on textboxes, can anyone please let me know what's going wrong in it?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to not use ref for form fields but rather use state to handle the form fields.

This is the sample react component to illustrate the same.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class FormTest extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            fName               : '',
            lName               : '',
        };
        this._bind(
            'changefName','changelName'
            );
    }

    _bind(...methods) {
      methods.forEach( (method) => this[method] = this[method].bind(this) );
     }

    changefName(e){
        this.setState({fName:e.target.value});
    }

    changelName(e){
        this.setState({lName:e.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        //Perform some stuff here

        //clear fields

        this.setState({
         fName:'',
         lName:''
         });
    }

    render(){

        return(

        <form className="form-horizontal" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-sm-6">
                 <fieldset>
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <div className="col-xs-12">
                            <label className="control-label" htmlFor="fName">Enter Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-xs-6">

                            <input id            = "lFName"
                            type                 = "text"
                            placeholder          = "First Name"
                            onChange             = {this.changefName}
                            value                = {this.state.fName}
                            className            = "form-control"
                            required autofocus/>

                        </div>
                        <div className="col-xs-6">

                            <input id            = "lLName"
                            type                 = "text"
                            placeholder          = "Last Name"
                            onChange             = {this.changelName}
                            value                = {this.state.lName}
                            className            = "form-control"
                            required autofocus/>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                 </fieldset>
            </div>
        </form>
         )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I can not go with mentioned way because I have 25 fields and I am not going to create 25 State Variable and 25 Change event